# How to have access to instance members in a static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, static, instance-variables

I'm trying to create classes to encapsulate validation and logic for objects like Email , URL , phone number and so on . in the first try I found that I'm repeating the same code in all classes specially static `IsValid` and the `Constructor` . so I decided to create a base class to put all the same codes in it . so there is a **base class** that other classes inherit it . it's **abstract** as I **don't** want it to be used **directly** .

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
            protected string value;
            private bool isValid;

            public bool IsValid{get { return this.isValid;}}

    protected virtual string RegexPattern{get;}

    protected virtual RegexOptions RegexOption{get;}

    private BaseClase(){}

    protected BaseClass(string value)
    {
        this.isValid = Validator.IsValid(value , RegexPattern, RegexOption);
        this.value = this.isValid ? value : string.Empty;
    }

    public static bool Validate(string value)
    {
        return Validator.IsValid(value ,RegexPattern, RegexOption); // rror
    }

}

public class Email
{
    private override string RegexPattern
    {
        get
        {
            return ".*";
        }
    }

    private override RegexOptions RegexOption
    {
        get
        {
            return RegexOptions.SingleLine;
        }
    }

            public string Address{get {return this.value; }}

    public Email(string address) : base(address){}
}
```

the problem is with the static `IsValid` method of BaseClass . in the current code it throws errors as `RegexPattern` and `RegexOption` are instance members . I don't want to defined the same value twice for instance and static methods . it works if I use

```
const string RegexPattern= ".*";
const RegexOptions RegexOption =RegexOptions.SingleLine;
```

but I need to be able to override these values in sub classes so this is not applicable . and as I have defined the `BaseClass` as `abstract` I cant instantiate it inside static method to have access to properties .

and as I want to use static method just like `Email.IsValid("foo@bar.com");` , I don't know how to pass an instance through it .

so , how can I have access to `RegexOption` and `RegexPattern` in this static method ?

Comment: You can pass an object reference via method parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so , how can I have access to PropOne and PropTwo in this static method ?

You need to have an instance *somehow*, otherwise it's a meaningless operation. So the question is - how would you *want* to identify the instance that you're interested in? Do you *really* need `Validate` to be static at all?

Note that instead of having abstract properties, if you expect the values to always stay the same throughout an instance of the class, you might want to make the values part of the constructor for `BaseClass` instead, and just keep them in fields.

If what you're trying to achieve is that each subclass has a single separate validator, I would separate the two concerns - give each subclass a static property *of a different type*. You wouldn't be able to call this polymorphically, but it sounds like you don't really want to anyway.

We can't really tell what your classes are meant to represent here - if you can give us more concrete context, we can probably be more helpful.

Comment: sorry , I'm always trying to make the question simple and general and so I'm always removing necessary parts too . I just updated the question . I hope it is clearer now

Comment: Not fully, because `BaseClass` doesn't give any indication about the *purpose of the class*. Is it meant to be a validator and *just* a validator, or something else? Do you really *need* subclasses, or just some pre-canned instances which validate different things?

Comment: really sorry , I Updated question . as I'm checking the code ,the only differences are the pattern and option and the name of the property that returns the value variable .

Answer (score -1):

you can try making `IsValid` an extension method.