# Accessing public methods in same class requires an Instance?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie to C# so forgive this question but I'm confused: Why do I need an instance of class Program to access method Sandbox which is public and in the same class?

```
namespace GoogleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Sandbox();            
        }

        public void Sandbox()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `public` from the test code. Ask the question again with the new information. Also, *search* for - *and report* - the error message you get when not "using an instance".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371839/is-it-possible-to-access-an-instance-variable-via-a-static-method , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871297/how-to-have-access-to-instance-members-in-a-static-method?rq=1

Comment: @user2864740: I'm not getting an error. I just can't see the non-static methods without an instance. I understand the basics as pointed out below. What was confusing was realizing I needed a Program instance **within Program itself**. Now I get it. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void Sandbox()
{
   ...
}
```

is the important part: This method is not marked static, so it is not callable on the **class**, but on **instances** of the class. If you want to be able to call it directly, you need

```
public static void Sandbox()
{
   ...
}
```

and can't use `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to access it from within a static method, but `Sandbox` is an instance method.

If you make `Sandbox` *static*, this won't be required:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    Sandbox();            
}

public static void Sandbox()
{
        ...
}
```

Note that it also doesn't have to be `public` - `public` allows it to be used by other classes and within other assemblies, but within `Program`, that's not required.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods exist at the `Class` level, you can consider them Global functions.  Any `non static` methods are instance level and just as the name implies you can only execute `instance` methods on an instance.  So by instantiating the class you have created an instance and now can call any `public` method.  In your example you could also call any `private` methods or constructors because you are creating the instance from with the class you are creating.